# PyQGIS: Aggregate function used with field calculator

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, aggregate

I'm using the following code with processing algorithm "Aggregate" to find neighbor polygons of some selected features in a polygon layer:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing

class DissolveAdjacentPolygons(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Inputpolygonlayer', 'Input polygon layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Agg', 'Agg', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Fixed', 'Fixed', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Fix geometries
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['Inputpolygonlayer'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Fixed']
        }
        outputs['FixGeometries'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Fixed'] = outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 250,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'Z930',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 2,
            'FORMULA': 'aggregate(\r\n layer:= \'Layer_name\',\r\n aggregate:=\'concatenate\',\r\n expression:=to_string(\"ZIPCODE\"),\r\n concatenator:=\', \',\r\n filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)),order_by:=$area\r\n )',
            'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Agg']
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Agg'] = outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Dissolve adjacent polygons'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Dissolve adjacent polygons'

    def group(self):
        return 'Dissolve'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Dissolve'

    def createInstance(self):
        return DissolveAdjacentPolygons()
```

This works fine, aggregates data based on field "ZIPCODE" in field "Z930", and sort the results by feature area.
The problem with de formula in the field calculator algorithm, is that the layer name (layer:= 'Layer_name') refers to an existing layer on the TOC, but I need to find a way to relate this 'Layer_name' with the output of the `native:fixgeometries` algorithm used above.
How can I do this?

Comment: The output of the algorithm `Fix geometries` is called `'Fixed geometries'` does that work in place of `'Layer name'`? You can also set the output name with `results['Fixed'].setName('my new layer name')`. Having said that, it may need to be loaded into the canvas for the expression to recognise it, but it could be immediately removed afterwards if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately no: Using 'Fixed geometries' gives the following error: Cannot find layer with name or ID 'Fixed geometries'. Trying  results['Fixed'].setName('my new layer name'), gives this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'setName' .

Comment: Are you able to make a layer from `results['Fixed']` with `QgsVectorLayer(results['Fixed'], 'layer name', 'memory')` and add it to the canvas? You would need to import `QgsVectorLayer` and `QgsProject` from `qgis.core`.

Comment: A 'Fixed Geometries' layer was already added to the canvas, but using the above suggestion, no other layer was added.

Comment: How about `@layer` in place of `\'Layer_name\'` in the expression? Fingers crossed.. I just tested in the Python console and it works there.

Comment: Works perfectly! Many thanks Matt.

Comment: Great to hear, it was a bit of a process of elimination. I have summarised as an answer to make it clearer for future visitors of your your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@layer` in place of `\'Layer_name\'` in the expression.

`@layer` is the variable name for the current layer that the `Field Calculator` is applied on.